# ionic capacitor run android --list not shoiwing virtual devices

Tags: capacitor

I'm trying to deploy a Capacitor 3 app to a virtual Android device using the command line. I have both a Pixel 3a running as an emulator and also a physical device connected. In Android studio, both appear and I can deploy to both. Also `adb devices` shows both phones.

However, `npx cap run android --list` only shows the physical device.

Is there some setting I need to enable to show the emulated device as well?

Thank you :-)

Comment: And in my case it is showing only emulators not my physical device.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue that I could fix by setting the SDK Platform Version from 31 to 30 in Android Studio SDK Manager. The reason why no virtual devices showed up, was that at the time Capacitor only supported version 30 and not 31.